# Relationship between compactness of a set and compactness of a linear operator

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness, compact-operators

I am recently learning functional analysis and topology, and I am wondering whether there is some relationship between compactness of a set (or a topological space) and compactness of a linear operator.

The definitions of two kinds of compactness are listed as below:

Definition 1: A topological space $(X, \tau)$ is compact iff every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover.

Definition 2: Let $X$, $Y$ be normed spaces and let $T \in L(X,Y)$. Then $T$ is compact iff for every bounded sequence $\{ x_n \}$ in $X$, $\{Tx_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence.

Hope someone can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: A subset $A$ of $Y$ is relatively compact if every sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ has a subsequence converging in $Y$. Thus a compact operator is a linear operator that sends bounded sets into relatively compact set. Also, a relatively compact set has compact closure, so a compact operator sends bounded sets to sets with compact closure.

Comment: It may help to first consider a less general linear space, such as a Hilbert space $\mathfrak{H}$.  Then in Hilbert space, the closed unit ball is weakly compact.  A bounded operator $T \in L(\mathfrak{H})$ is compact if and only if $T|_{B}: B \longrightarrow \mathfrak{H}$ is continuous.  That is, $T(B)$ is compact.

Comment: Thanks very much guys! I will consider what you guys have said carefully!